# upload SVG clear width, height, style inline and set ViewBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, backbone.js

I ask when I upload svg file is there any way to remove the inline style, width, height and set of svg ViewBox.

Comment: Do you want to remove spesific parts of SVG code automatically when uploading to server?  Question is a bit hard to understand.

Comment: with javascript via removeAttribute

Comment: remove svg, g, path and set ViewBox on svg

Comment: @Robert Longson $('.svgUpload').removeAttribute() is not a function ?

Comment: You're mixing jquery with ordinary DOM. In jQuery it's [removeAttr](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: and set ViewBox SVG @Robert Longson

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ might work (or it might set the attribute name to lowercase which would fail). You're better off using ordinary DOM for SVG rather than jquery which is only designed to work with html

Comment: @Robert Longson thank you very much